# Mejor metodo para encriptar contraseñas en mssql con php

Tags: php, seguridad, encriptación, tsql

Cual seria el mejor metodo para encriptar contraseñas en una base de datos. En mi caso tengo que encriptar dos contraseñas por usuario: la de acceso del propio usuario y la de su cuenta de email.

La primera seria en un solo sentido, comparando la contraseña introducida con la almacenada en mssql, pero la segunda necesito que sea en los dos sentidos (encriptar y desencriptar), ya que la necesito para que el usuario se valide al enviar un email a través de php.

El servidor que estoy utilizando tiene instalado PHP Version 5.5.33-1~dotdeb+7.1

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El proceso de encriptar las contraseñas para proteger las cuentas de los usuarios es algo muy importante en una aplicación, existen diferentes tipos de algoritmos, una implementación común en PHP es **blowfish**, porque es lento y previene ataques por fuerza bruta:

```
<?php  

function get_hash($password, $cost = 11) {
    // Genera sal de forma aleatoria
    $salt=substr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(17)),0,22);
    // reemplaza caracteres no permitidos
    $salt=str_replace("+",".",$salt);
    // genera una cadena con la configuración del algoritmo
    $param='$'.implode('$',array(
        "2y", // versión más segura de blowfish (>=PHP 5.3.7)
        str_pad($cost,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT), // costo del algoritmo
        $salt // añade la sal
    ));

    // obtiene el hash de la contraseña
    return crypt($password,$param);
}

function validate_pass($hash, $pass) {
    // verifica la contraseña con el hash
    return crypt($pass, $hash) == $hash;
}

$hash = get_hash("miPassword");
echo $hash . '<br />'; //      $2y$11$VWjsiQG3cwASWxcDu4XQyOKifKFSWxoAVIL0yd8KJ4laPfDsWz20.

$isValid = validate_pass($hash, "miPassword");
echo $isValid ? 'válida' : 'no válida'; // válida
?>
```

Además esta implementación incluye el uso de una *sal* para prevenir ataques con *rainbow tables* que son tablas pre-generadas de contraseñas comunes. En este [post](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2016/05/almacenamiento-seguro-de-contrasenas/) puedes encontrar más detalles sobre el almacenamiento seguro de contraseñas.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportacion, me ha ayudado mucho. Y que método es el más seguro para encriptar contraseñas de correo electrónico, que posteriormente tengo que desencriptar para porder usar. Mcrypt?

Answer (score 3):

Te han dejado ejemplos muy practicos, una alternativa muy utilizado hoy un dia es `password_hash()` con `password_verify()`, para almacenar contraseña de manera segura.

> **password_hash()** crea un nuevo hash de contraseña usando un algoritmo de hash fuerte de único sentido. password_hash() es compatible con crypt(). Por lo tanto, los hash de contraseñas creados con crypt() se pueden usar con password_hash().

Veamos un caso, como podría quedar.

**Encriptar contraseña:**

```
//Contraseña usuario formulario.
$password = 'hola mundo';

//Encriptamos nuestra contraseña para BD.
$password = password_hash(
                base64_encode(
                    hash('sha384', $password, true)
                ), PASSWORD_DEFAULT
            );

//SQL, insertamos nuestra contraseña a BD,etc...
```

El resultado de `$password` seria algo similar a:

- $2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a

> **password_verify()**, comprueba que el hash proporcionado coincida con la contraseña facilitada.
>   
>   Observe que password_hash() devuelve el algoritmo, el coste y la sal como parte del hash devuelto. Por lo tanto, toda la información que es necesaria para verificar el hash está incluida. Esto permite a la función de verificación comprobar el hash sin la necesidad de almacenar por separado la información de la sal o del algoritmo.

**Verificar contraseña:**

```
//Obtenemos datos formulario.
$password = 'hola mundo';
$usuario = 'Foo';

//Obtenemos el password desde BD.
$sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT password FROM usuario WHERE email=? LIMIT 1");

//$passwordBaseDatos, es la contraseña desde BD.
//Es decir,  $2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a

//Verificamos nuestras contraseñas.
if (password_verify(
      base64_encode(
        hash('sha384', $password, true)
      ), $passwordBaseDatos
)) {
  echo'Tu contraseña fue verificado correctamente';
} else {
  echo'Tu contraseña no coincide';
}
```

Aquí te dejo otra información de SOes con ejemplos prácticos que quizás te pueda venir útil [Almacenamiento de contraseñas PHP y MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql) o [¿Como obtener siempre los mismos resultados al encriptar una cadena?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33376/como-obtener-siempre-los-mismos-resultados-al-encriptar-una-cadena)

Answer (score 1):

Mejor o peor son términos muy subjetivos algunas veces, y depende mucho de la experiencia y el caso concreto.

Te puedo decir una buena forma de hacerlo

```
<?php

    $myPassword = 'foobar';

    $opciones = [
        'cost' => 12,
    ];

    $password = password_hash($myPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);

?>
```

Para el cifrado de doble sentido, puedes usar [openssl_encrypt](https://secure.php.net/openssl_encrypt) y [openssl_decrypt](https://secure.php.net/openssl_decrypt)

Answer (score -1):

Encriptalo desde PHP

```
<?php
$password = 'Este es mi password';
$passwordMD5 = md5($password);
?>
```

Espero te haya servido, saludos!