# ¿Como obtener siempre los mismos resultados al encriptar una cadena?

Tags: php, encriptación

Tengo esta función que sirve para encriptar cadenas:

```
public function encriptar($string) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), 
                            MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $encrypted = base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                                                    hash('sha256', getKey(), true), 
                                                    $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));    
    return $encrypted;
}
```

El problema es que siempre me retorna un valor distinto aun añadiendo la misma cadena. Ejemplo:

> Introduzco: StackOverflow
>
> Resultado: InT3g0AUXXTrmCAxrlht5ZVe8GBmlgGDMotXuVu11hI=

Si vuelvo a ejecutar el script:

> Introduzco: StackOverflow
>
> Resultado: ImhWn5vPA/A2NY2wpUwg7VLWAiGBls80Z84fGU303Ws=

Si vuelvo a ejecutar el script:

> Introduzco: StackOverflow
>
> Resultado: FqvxSsblSwz5riaDnnq7h20PzZTPdk/K+dikLHbLHTY=

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que siempre sea el mismo valor?

Comment: Explica un poco para que es...  de donde es... hay una función para desencriptar?

Comment: @albertoMier lo que hace tu algoritmo es valido, lo que hace es encriptarlo diferente, pero cuando lo desencriptas vuelve a ser la misma cadena

Answer (score 12):

### Respuesta corta

Si siempre obtienes el mismo resultado, el mecanismo de cifrado es demasiado débil.

### Respuesta larga

> El problema es que siempre me retorna un valor distinto aun añadiendo la misma cadena.

Este es el comportamiento esperado. Al especificar `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` y `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` estas usando cifrado `AES` compatible, en modo `CBC`. Este modo incluye/requiere un ***vector de inicializacion aleatorio***, conocido como IV (que en tu código inicializas en la primera linea). Esta es la razón por la que el valor es siempre diferente, por el vector aleatorio.

El modo `CBC` (o [cipher block chaining](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modos_de_operaci%C3%B3n_de_una_unidad_de_cifrado_por_bloques#Modo_CBC_.28Cipher-block_chaining.29)) utiliza un `IV` al iniciar el cifrado (y el descifrado) que hace mucho mas robusto el algoritmo. El `IV` no es un número random sin sentido, **debes compartir** el vector de inicialización al otro lado (el descifrador) para que pueda hacer el descifrado. Esto sólo hace a la clave un poco mas compleja pues cuenta con dos partes, la clave simétrica (la clave `AES`) y el vector de inicialización (el `IV`).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la razón por la que tu método esta "concatenando" el `IV` al valor cifrado, porque luego se necesita del otro lado para iniciar el descifrado.

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que siempre sea el mismo valor?

Mi recomendación es que **no hagas esto**, no importa que los valores no sean iguales. Lo mas importante es que el cifrado sea robusto.

Lo mejor sería que sigas usando lo que estas usando: `CBC` y envíes el `IV` y que el otro lado inicie el vector apropiadamente y descifre el contenido.

Pero si insistes en recibir el mismo valor, fíjate en otras respuestas que te sugieren cambiar el método de cifrado a `ECB`. Es poco recomendable porque ese modo es obsoleto y aunque se conserva por compatibilidad es muy vulnerable.

Para completar la respuesta, el modo ECB encripta cada bloque (que son del mismo largo que la clave) de forma independiente. Esto quiere decir que si encriptas un email, todos aquellos mensajes que provengan de la misma fuente, una vez encriptados comenzaran con la misma secuencia encriptada!!! (pues todos comenzaran con el bloque: `From: <juan.perez@gmail.com>\n`, generando al menos un patrón perceptible a cualquier interesado en su contenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los otros modos (como `CBC`) que incluyen un `IV` (o intialization vector) aleatorio, encriptan cada bloque utilizando parte del bloque anterior, por lo que son mucho mas robustos. En esta imagen puede visualizarse la diferencia entre el modo `ECB` y cualquier otro modo que incluya aleatoriedad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas Informacion:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/967/aes-in-ecb-mode-weakness

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption

Comment: como nota, en CBC puedes usar un IV nulo, el cual hara que siempre retorne los mismos valores, pero esto no es muy recomendable tampoco por que reduce la fuerza final del cifrado.

Comment: muy buena explicación!!

Comment: Una explicación muy completa en la que queda muy claro el porque en un sistema de encriptación no debería devolver la misma encriptación para una misma cadena. +1

Comment: Muy buena explicación. +1

Answer (score 4):

Vamos por partes:

1. Tu código no muestra la forma en la que se genera la llave `getKey()`
2. Estás usando una función de cifrado que usa un sector de inicialización `$iv`
3. `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` está generando datos aleatorios cada vez que llamas a la función `encriptar()`

Ahora, para poder obtener el mismo string siempre debes usar siempre el mismo juego de `$iv`, llave y texto. Puedes generar el `$iv` en base64 y verlo en pantalla con `print_r` o `echo`, luego lo usarías en tu función en algo como:

```
$iv = base64_decode('230487298384920weuiw'); //esta sería
```

De esta forma siempre obtendrás el mismo resultado al cifrar tu texto.

Dependiendo de la aplicación que le des esto puede o no ser bueno, si estás cifrando contraseñas te sugiero que revises la función [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) que implementa bcrypt, luego puedes usar `password_verify` para saber si tu password está bien o no.

Espero te sirva...

Comment: Utilizar el mismo `IV` en todas las pasadas reduce la robustez del algoritmo y se considera una mala practica. No debe recomendarse sin una aclaración que permita tomar la decisión correcta de si/no usar un `IV` fijo.

Comment: Es una mala práctica en general pero el OP está solicitando eso... Además estoy aclarando que depende del uso de este algoritmo será o no una mala práctica pues todo depende del nivel de seguridad que se quiera alcanzar.

Answer (score 4):

> Con el modo `CBC`, se supone que es para obtener un texto cifrado diferente cada vez que la función de cifrado se llama, incluso con el mismo texto plano.

Esta propiedad proporciona protección contra ciertos tipos de ataques, y es una de las razones por las `CBC` es más seguro que el `BCE`.

**¿Cómo obtener siempre los mismos resultados al encriptar una cadena?**

Está creando un diferente `$iv` uso `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` como el pseudo-aleatorio de números-generador.

Si aún desea hacerlo (y sólo debe hacerlo si realmente sabe lo que está haciendo), se debe utilizar el mismo vector de inicialización `$iv`, y el resultado será el mismo.

> **Nota:** Pero como se ha dicho, esto puede comprometer la seguridad del sistema.

**Un punto adicional:** Usted puede almacenar en su base de datos, en la instancia de clase, o almacenarla como un prefijo / sufijo del último hash.

Aunque usted no debe volver a utilizar el `$iv` fines de seguridad...

**Una segunda opción:** Es generar una sola vez y guardarlo en la base de datos y volver a utilizarlo.

```
function getIv($database) {
    // fictive database abstraction layer
    $iv = $database->fetchIv();
    if (!$iv) {
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
            mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), 
            MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        );
        $database->saveIv($iv);
    }

    return $iv;
}

// in your class

public function encriptar($string) {
    $encrypted = base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                                                    hash('sha256', getKey(), true), 
                                                    $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, getIv()));    
    return $encrypted;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Debería estar usando `openssl_encrypt()` y `openssl_decrypt()`

`mcrypt` no es una buena idea ya que no se ha actualizado desde 2007.

Incluso hay un RFC para eliminar `mcrypt` de `PHP`

- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral

Fuente SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption/9262137#9262137

### Ejemplo: `openssl_encrypt()` y `openssl_decrypt()`

```
<?php
 /**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption/30189841#30189841      
 */
    class UnsafeCrypto
    {
        const METHOD = 'aes-256-ctr';

        /**
         * Encrypts (pero no autentificar) un mensaje.
         * 
         * @param cadena $mensaje - mensaje texto plano
         * @param cadena $clave - clave encriptado (raw binary expected) (binario sin procesar)
         * @param booleano $codificar - establecido en TRUE para devolver un base64-encoded 
         * @return cadena (raw binary)
         */
        public static function encrypt($mensaje, $clave, $codificar = false)
        {
            $tamano = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::METHOD);
            $mientras = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($tamano);

            $texto_cifrado = openssl_encrypt(
                $mensaje,
                self::METHOD,
                $clave,
                OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
                $mientras
            );

            // Ahora empaquemos el IV y el texto cifrado
            // Nativamente, sólo podemos concatenar
            if ($codificar) {
                return base64_encode($mientras.$texto_cifrado);
            }
            return $mientras.$texto_cifrado;
        }

        /**
         * Decrypts (pero no autentificar) un mensaje.
         * 
         * @param cadena $mensaje - mensaje texto plano
         * @param cadena $clave - clave encriptado (raw binary expected)
         * @param booleano $codificado - ¿Esperamos una cadena codificada?
         * @return cadena
         */
        public static function decrypt($mensaje, $clave, $codificado = false)
        {
            if ($codificado) {
                $mensaje = base64_decode($mensaje, true);
                if ($mensaje === false) {
                    throw new Exception('Encriptación fallido');
                }
            }

            $tamano = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::METHOD);
            $mientras = mb_substr($mensaje, 0, $tamano, '8bit');
            $texto_cifrado = mb_substr($mensaje, $tamano, null, '8bit');

            $texto_plano = openssl_decrypt(
                $texto_cifrado,
                self::METHOD,
                $clave,
                OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
                $mientras
            );

            return $texto_plano;
        }
    }

$mensaje = 'Hola mundo.';
$clave = hex2bin('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');

$encriptado = UnsafeCrypto::encrypt($mensaje, $clave);
$descifrado  = UnsafeCrypto::decrypt($encriptado, $clave);

echo 'Mensaje encriptada: ' . $encriptado . '<br />';
echo 'Mensaje descifrada: ' . $descifrado  . '<br />';
?>
```

Salida de `echo`, quedaría algo como:

```
Mensaje encriptada: I��Y6��� �q_��d���lO1�?�<br />
Mensaje descifrada: Hola mundo.
```

Fuente:

- https://3v4l.org/jl7qR

Fuente SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption/30189841#30189841

> **Nota:** en caso querer guardar contraseñas mediante `PHP` y `MySQL`, te aconsejo que utilices `password_hash()` y `password_verify()`

`password_hash()` crea un nuevo hash de contraseña usando un algoritmo de hash fuerte de único sentido. `password_hash()` es compatible con `crypt()`. Por lo tanto, los hash de contraseñas creados con `crypt()` se pueden usar con `password_hash()`.

`password_verify` — comprueba que el hash proporcionado coincida con la contraseña facilitada.

Observe que `password_hash()` devuelve el algoritmo, el coste y la sal como parte del hash devuelto. Por lo tanto, toda la información que es necesaria para verificar el hash está incluida. Esto permite a la función de verificación comprobar el hash sin la necesidad de almacenar por separado la información de la sal o del algoritmo.

Más información en fuente SOes:

- [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%c3%b1as-php-y-mysql/33433#33433](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql/33433#33433)

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres guardar las contraseñas de tus usuarios sería horroroso que siempre salga la misma cadena cifrada, pero he leído en los comentarios que es para los emails, vale.

Entonces, si cifras una cadena tiene que a ver otra función que la descifra y la función que usas no es apto para lo que creo que necesitas.

Te dejo una función extraído de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16606352/2097224):

**¡Estas funciones no son seguros ni apto para guardar contraseñas!**

```
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted_string;
}


define("LLAVE_SECRETA", "!@#$%^&*");

$string = 'Hola Mari Carmen';

$encrypt = encrypt($string, LLAVE_SECRETA);

echo $encrypt; // ��0we��[�;���v

$decrypt = decrypt($encrypt, LLAVE_SECRETA);

echo $decrypt; // Hola Mari Carmen
```

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ebf7b052eed22c68e989c494ac98f9a6127eb440)

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.

Si usas Laravel, la forma de autenticar es usar las funciones del framework, siempre es menos engorroso.

Mira un ejemplo desde el [sitio oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing):

Para crear el Hash puedes hacer

```
// obtener la contraseña desde formulario
$contrasena = Hash::make(Input::get('pass_usuario'));
```

Para comprobar que el password funciona:

```
if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword)){
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Un ejemplo de enrolamiento sería

```
function login (Request $request){
    $idUsuario = $request['id_usuario'];
    $passUsuario = $request['pass_usuario'];

    $usuario = Usuarios::find ($idUsuario);

    // se usar la contraseña y el hash como parametros
    if (Hash::check($passUsuario, $usuario->CONTRASENA)) {

          // usar Session para mantener la sesion del usuario (esto es un ejemplo solamente :P)
          Session::put('id', $idUsuario);

          // redirigir al inicio
          return redirect('inicio/');
    } else {
          // devolver error al cliente
          return response()->json(array('error' => 'No se ha podido enrolar'));
    }
}
```

Tengo que destacar que para agregar estas funciones debes crear la semilla en el fichero de configuración `.env` de la siguiente manera:

```
 php artisan key:generate
```

Tambien debes agregar a la cabecera:

```
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Session;
```

La documentacion de `Session` está en el [Sitio Oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session)
La documentación de `Redirect` está en el [Sitio oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects)
La documentación de `Response()->json` está en el [Sitio oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses)

Ahora si me preguntas si es correcto Cifrar los correos, te diré que no.
¿Donde piensas guardar las contraseñas con las que se cifran? ¿En la misma base de datos? ¿Como vas a manejar los permisos para acceder a esas contraseñas?
Creo que cifrar los Emails solo hacen que tu aplicacion necesite mas recursos al momento de acceder, ademas de que hacen que tu aplicacion sea menos mantenible.

Mira estas respuestas en StackOverflow Ingles: [Is it worth encrypting email addresses in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70450/is-it-worth-encrypting-email-addresses-in-the-database)

Answer (score 1):

No existe ningún problema si la cadena generada no es igual cada vez que se genera, siempre y cuando tengas un `key` es posible desencriptarla a la cadena original. Mira el siguiente código:

```
<?php
function encriptar($key='', $cadena = ''){
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
        mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),
        MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        );

    $encrypted = base64_encode(
        $iv .
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            hash('sha256', $key, true),
            $cadena,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $iv
        )
    );
    return $encrypted;
}


function desencriptar($key='', $cadena = ''){
    $data = base64_decode($cadena);
    $iv = substr($data, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

    $decrypted = rtrim(
        mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            hash('sha256', $key, true),
            substr($data, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)),
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $iv
        ),
        "\0"
    );
    return $decrypted;
}

$key = 'key para encriptar';
$string = 'stack overflow';
echo "Datos oginales:<br>key: ".$key."<br>cadena:".$string;
$encryptedstring = encriptar($key, $string);
echo "<br><br>cadena encriptada:".$encryptedstring;
$decryptedstring = desencriptar($key, $encryptedstring);
echo "<br><br>cadena desencriptada:".$decryptedstring;
?>
```

Sin embargo esta no es buena practica para encriptar contraseñas, además de ser un método viejo (aunque no está [deprecado](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mcrypt.php)).

Si lo que quieres es encriptar una cadena y siempre obtener el mismo resultado al encriptar, prueba lo siguiente:

```
$string = 'stack overflow';
// encriptar
$hash = crypt($string, 'st');
echo "<br>encriptado: ".$hash;
// verificar
if (crypt($string, $hash) == $hash) {
    echo "<br>si, correcto!!";
}
```

la función `crypt(str,salt)` genera una clave siempre contante. ver atributos [aquí para generar salt de manera correcta](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_crypt.asp)

Pero, si lo que quieres es tener alta seguridad a pesar de no generar siempre la misma clave, prueba con [password_hash](http://php.net/password_hash) y [password_verify](http://php.net/password_verify). Primero, para encriptar:

```
// forma 1:
$hash = password_hash('rasmuslerdorf', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// forma 2:
$options = [
   'cost' => 11
];
$hash = password_hash('rasmuslerdorf', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Para desencriptar:

```
if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Ver [Constantes predefinidas](http://php.net/manual/es/password.constants.php)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que veo es que la función `mcrypt_create_iv()` como hace que el valor de `$iv` sea aleatorio, eso jode tu función, por que el parámetro que mandas a la siguiente función `base64_encode()` siempre es diferente, mi sugerencia es:

Maneja `$iv` como una variable de configuración global en un archivo como `config.php` y cámbiala manualmente por cada instalación de tu sistema.

También puedes generar el archivo `config.php` durante la instalación y ahí generas el valor que tendría la variable `$iv`.